# Rails 3 - Update every attribute that is present in a model instance (encode every value)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encode

I want to encode the values for every attribute in a model instance. Does Rails 3 support something like this? For example

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :author, :description
end
```

By default the attribute values for title, author, and description are encoded as UTF-8. Instead I want to update all the attribute values and encode them as ISO. There will be cases where the model might have 50+ attributes and doesn't make sense to call each attribute individually. It would be preferable to update all the attributes in one shot.

Here is some pseudocode for what I'm trying to do. Is something like this possible in Rails 3?

```
Book.find(1).update_all_attributes(&:encode("ISO-8859-1"))
```

*Update* I know that the above line of code will fail. It's just pseudocode to help communicate what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: First of all, your expected code will raise a syntax error.

Comment: Yeah, it was just pseudocode to help communicate what I'm trying to do

Comment: It is nonsense, even as pseudocode.

Comment: Going out of your way to comment on the obvious and offer nothing of value is nonsense.

Comment: *(asking for clarification / refinement is usually best in these circumstances).* There's no direct method that I'm aware of that updates attributes of a model without explicitly naming them. Is there any kind of naming convention to these columns?

Comment: yup! Each column name is prefixed with "pn_"

Comment: @Smooth Mori's answer is probably the most straightforward way. The only other option I was considering is building a hash and passing it to `update_attributes` or `assign_attributes`, but that would likely require more work in the end if you can't infer the entire name of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :recode_attribs

  private

  def recode_attribs
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      next unless value.respond_to?(:encode)
      attributes[name] = value.encode('ISO-8859-1')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What if I only need to encode when the user chooses to do so through the UI? Is it dangerous to make this a non-private method and call it in the controller prior to saving the model instance?

Comment: @Smooth, that sounds non-dangerous. The `before_save` is useful when there are multiple places where the record can be saved and you want to catch them all.